# Seeking Python module to find volume of xyz data

Tags: python, software-recommendations, xyz, volume

I have an xyz file in the following format:

```
720567.698,733950.021,-4.20
720567.698,733949.021,-4.04
720567.698,733948.021,-3.86
720567.698,733947.021,-3.68
720567.698,733946.021,-3.45
720567.698,733945.021,-3.23
720567.698,733944.021,-3.10
720567.698,733943.021,-2.98
```

I use gdal_grid to create a raster TIFF from this data, but I am now wondering is there a good Python module to calculate the volume of a specified area?

For example if I were to draw a small rectangular box within them coordinates, I would need the volume of that wee rectangle.

A Python way is preferred to match in with my current code

Answer (score 1):

There are a few algorithms in QGIS that might be able to help you. I don't understand what you want to achieve, but the following algorithm might help you:

```
# first, set the name of your raster/TIFF file
rasterName = "myRasterName"

canvas = iface.mapCanvas() # first, define the map canvas by referencing iface
layers = canvas.layers() # gather all layers into a list
for lyr in layers: # loop through layers
   if lyr.name() == rasterName:
      raster = lyr

res = processing.run("native:rastersurfacevolume", {
    'INPUT': raster,\
    'BAND': 1,\
    'LEVEL': 0,\
    'METHOD': None,\
    'OUTPUT_HTML_FILE': None,\
    'OUTPUT_TABLE': None,\
    'OUTPUT': 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'
})
output = res["OUTPUT"]
output.setName("My Raster Volume Layer")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(output)
```

This can be run by:

1. Opening QGIS
2. Opening a new project
3. Dragging and dropping your TIFF file into the map canvas
4. Pressing Ctr + Alt + P to open up the Python console
5. Click the "Show editor" button to open up the editor menu
6. Click the green plus to open up a blank script
7. Paste the above code into the blank script
8. Change the rasterName variable to match the name of the TIFF layer
9. Press the green play button to run the script

This algorithm can be also run in the QGIS GUI for testing purposes:
[image: qgis raster volume alg]